# Error Message - Unsupported Operand Types

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have now updated my question. The only part of my code that is not running is the values. I keep getting the error message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/Circle.py", line 11, in 
    xvalues.append((r * math.cos) * (math.tan * (1/n)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'"
Does anybody know why that might be?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

xvalues = []
yvalues = []

n = 6
r = 4

for r in range (0, n+1):
    xvalues.append((r * math.cos) * (math.tan * (1/n)))
    yvalues.append((r * math.sin) * (math.tan * (1/n)))


print(xvalues)
print(yvalues)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_title(f'''Approx. with {n} points''', fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=14)

plt.style.use('seaborn')

ax.plot(xvalues, yvalues, linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Or your problem come from missing bracket:

```
for r in range (0, n+1):
    xvalues.append(r * math.cos (math.tan * 1/n)
    yvalues.append(r * math.sin (math.tan * 1/n)
```

To correct for:

```
for r in range (0, n+1):
    xvalues.append(r * math.cos (math.tan * 1/n)) 
    yvalues.append(r * math.sin (math.tan * 1/n))
```

Or/and come from spaces:

```
fig ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set title(f"Approx. with {n} points", fontsize=24)
ax.set xlabel("x", fontsize=14)
ax.set ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
```

To replace by:

```
ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title(f"Approx. with {n} points", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
```

Comment: I fixed that! Thank you, but I am still getting an error message on the a in "ax"

Comment: And replace fig ax = plt.subplots() by ax=plt.subplots()

Comment: I figured out I needed a comma but now I got an error message saying "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/Circle.py", line 11, in <module>
    xvalues.append(r * math.cos (math.tan * 1/n))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'"

Comment: I got an error message saying "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Documents/Circle.py", line 11, in <module> xvalues.append(r * math.cos (math.tan * 1/n)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'" –

Comment: Are you trying to calculate r*cos(tan(1/n))?

Comment: I am just trying to create a hexagon

Comment: I dont know if it will create an hexagon, but error come from missing brackets in part: for r in range (0, n+1):
    xvalues.append(r * math.cos (math.tan ( 1/n) )) 
    yvalues.append(r * math.sin (math.tan ( 1/n)))